# Is it STILL possible in FB JS API to upload photo to Page's album

Tags: facebook-graph-api, upload, facebook-php-sdk, photo, facebook-page

Is it STILL possible in FB JS API to upload photo to Page's album?

What i forgot to say, is that any user (no need to be Page manager) should be allowed to upload photo to Page's album. It worked this way before.

I mean, i tried everything.
my code is

```
FB.api('/'+albumID+'/photos?no_story=1', 'post', {
    message: 'created by: '+userNameString,
    url: imgURL
}, function(response) { .......
```

Everytime, the error is #120 - Invalid album id. Ive double checked the id hundred times. It still seems to be right.

Tried also including long-lived token there. About 1,5 year ago i made succesfull working app, that now i need to refurbish and publish and nothing seems to be working.

If anyone of You got similar work to do, maybe can share the methodology of getting acces token for such a case? Couse i started to believe that it is the reason of this error.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, answer can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/